# How can the name of an app with many files be easily changed?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the name of my iOS App, how can I easily change the name without going through each file and possible locations that I have used the old name

Comment: You want to rename the project or the app display name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace all occurrences in the project from the project navigator.

[image]